# What types of keyboard does Neo/Mr Anderson use?

Tags: the-matrix, object-identification, props

I like how Neo's room is detailed and have recently developed an interest in keyboard choices and keyboards in general.

**What sort of (prop) keyboards is Neo using?**

The newer keyboard seems to be some sort of ergonomic one, the older resembles a mainframe keyboard.

[image]

Comment: @TangoOversway other than being for fun, consider that Neo could serve as an ideal to many hacker-wannabes and the cast may have chosen a keyboard very carefully to avoid RSI && maximize productivity.

Comment: item 8 is called a CD, item 4 looks like a book!

Comment: It's amazing how lo-tech and dated that whole scene looks nowadays, classic Sci-Fi entropy

Comment: @Adrian sure looks dated :D but I don't think it's a problem here. I think it's more like a documentary of the 90s, it wasn't meant to look high-tech, it was meant to look hacker-ish... it actually is geeky. Also the simulation of Matrix is set in an age where line phones were commonplace while computers of today and the internet was only emerging.

Comment: What are those big white boxes that the LCDs are mounted on?

Comment: @TGnat I think you mean the CRTs... as someone your age would know I suppose. :(

Comment: @TGnat I'm going to guess those boxes are Intel 80486DX2 enclosures.

Comment: @Withywindle - I've identified the other keyboard. Now just to wait for this to get reopened...

Comment: @Valorum I think your edit makes the older comments unintelligible, because (although having neat hand-drawn-circles) your image lacks the number annotations people are referring to.

Comment: @Bitmask - The OP had labelled a lot of weird stuff including a CD and a telephone but asked about the keyboards. I thought I'd make it more focused.

Comment: Technically, a virtual keyboard.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks an awful lot like the [Generation 1 - Microsoft Natural Keyboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Natural_keyboard) to me.

[image]

Comment: I retract my previous comment, I just understood that it is also the name of the first model. Next closest is the "Elite" model but I think that it has different arrow keys. The wiki has a photo of a "Pro" one.

Comment: My boss has one of these and swears but it. You can hear the "clakcity-clack-clack-clack-tchk-tchk-clack" from about eight offices down. He does it on purpose.

Comment: @Withywindle Don't ever introduce your boss to the [Model M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_M_keyboard), also known as the "clicky keyboard". (Yes, they are still available for purchase new.)

Comment: That might be the one I'm talking about. If not, I know what I'm getting my boss for Christmas >:}

Answer (score 6):

Neo is using two keyboards in that scene. The first, [already identified](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/18669/20774) is the [Microsoft Natural Keyboard Pro V1 (1999)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Natural_Keyboard#Natural_Keyboard_Pro)

[image]

The second appears to be a [(Keytronic) Wang 725 PC Terminal Keyboard (1989/1990)](http://utensilia.tk/keytronic-wang_36355-2-725-3488-us/).

[image]