# What brand is this decanter from Alita: Battle Angel?

Tags: object-identification, alita-battle-angel

Vector pours a whiskey for Hugo at the 117 minute mark.

**Does anyone know the brand of the decanter and glasses?**

[image: A close up of the studded decanter with whiskey in it] [image: A close up of the matching glass]

I would like to buy but can't find details.

Comment: Is this question on-topic?

Comment: @Taladris there have been previous questions like this ([What is the manufacturer/brand of the glass that Dr. Crusher breaks?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/192491/98028), [What types of keyboard does Neo/Mr Anderson use?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/18665/98028)). I can't see it being off-topic for any of our close reasons; it being _interesting_ is another matter however.

Comment: @Jenayah: it can happen that off-topic questions may not be caught by the net of the moderators, so I am not convinced. I think it is off-topic because it is not about scifi or fantasy (I think the SE terminology for this is boat programming).

Comment: @Taladris - Why would it be off-topic? The [FAQ](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) specifically mentions *"Behind-the-scenes and fandom information*" and this is arguably far more helpful (since he's actually wanting to buy them with his real money) than a question about [how many animals are seen inside the Matrix](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71564/why-are-there-no-animals-in-the-matrix/71566#71566) or [whether ACME is the only company in the Loony Tunes universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/205001/20774) which are fun, but are of no conceivable use to anyone.

Answer (score 11):

This appears to be the [CB2 Exclusive *Stud Decanter*](https://www.cb2.com/stud-decanter/s134665) and the semi-matching [*Leela Barware Glasses*](https://www.cb2.com/leela-barware/f22043)

[image: The Stud Decanter with the stopper in the top]

[image: The semi-matching whiskey glass next to a taller spirit glass]